# Clear value from Firebase in ReactJS weekly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a React app that uses Firebase. In order to display weekly data, I use this endpoint to get the week number from Cloud Functions:

```
exports.getWeekNumberApi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ week: getWeekNumber(new Date()) }));
    })
});
```

GetWeekNumber returns the week number.

Now I don't want to call this api all the time, but I'm not sure how to cache and clear the data so it won't run of when the week changes. If a user visits the app on Sunday evening, the api should be called and cache cleared Sunday at midnight. Any idea how this can be done in React?

Only thing I can think of is to set a cookie and calculate how long before sunday midnight, and just clear the cookie a little after that.

Answer (score -1):

To help us deal with when to increment the week counter on the front-end uniformly across clients, you should return the timestamp of when the week would increase.

To get this timestamp, we create a `Date` instance, change its time to midnight and then set it to the next Sunday. In your deployed Cloud Functions code, you can achieve this using the following function:

```js
// Gets a Date object representing the next Sunday at 00:00
// Note: Functions run in the UTC timezone, so this code works
//       without UTC offset adjustments
getDateForFutureSundayAtMidnight() {
  const d = new Date();
  // set time to midnight (00:00)
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // set date to the next Sunday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 7);
  return d;
}
```

Then you edit your `getWeekNumberApi` function to be:

```js
exports.getWeekNumberApi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const expiresDate = getDateForFutureSundayAtMidnight();

        res.json({
          week: getWeekNumber(new Date()),
          expires: expiresDate.getTime()
        });
    })
});
```

As a simplification, as shown above, you can use `response.json(/* object */)` in place of setting the `Content-Type` and stringifying the object yourself.

On the client side, instead of using cookies, you can store the result in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Here, we check the local cache to see if any responses have been stored and if not, we call the API and store its response.

```js
// synchronous function, only queries cache
function getCachedResponse(id, fallback = null) {
  const cached = window.localStorage.getItem(id)
  if (cached !== null) {
    const cachedObject = JSON.parse(cached);
    if (Date.now() < cachedObject.expires)
      return cachedObject;
  }
  return fallback;
}

// asynchronous function, calls API when expired/not available
async function fetchAndCacheResponse(id, url) {
  const cached = window.localStorage.getItem(id);

  if (cached !== null) {
    const cachedObject = JSON.parse(cached);
    if (Date.now() < cachedObject.expires)
      return cachedObject;
  }

  // calls API
  const res = await fetch(url);

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(url + " returned unexpected status code: " + res.status);
  }

  const bodyString = res.text();
  window.localStorage.setItem(id, bodyString);

  return JSON.parse(bodyString);
}

// Usage:
// fetchCachedResponse("myApp:week", "https://us-central1-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/getWeekNumberApi");
```

In your component/service, you can then apply this using a `useEffect` call.

```js
// set initial week number to -1 while loading or use
// a cached value if available & valid
const [weekNumber, setWeekNumber] = useState(() => getCachedResponse("myApp:week", -1));
const [weekNumberLoading, setWeekNumberLoading] = useState(weekNumber !== -1);

useEffect(() => {
  let timerID, disposed = false;

  fetchCachedResponse("myApp:week", "https://us-central1-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/getWeekNumberApi")
    .then((response) => {
      if (disposed) return; // component was unmounted/result is stale, do nothing

      const timeToNextIncrement = response.expires - Date.now();
      const weekNumber = response.week;

      // schedule the next update and update the state's week number
      // NOTE: This is for 1-based week numbers: 1-52
      //       Use `(weekNumber + 1) % 52` for 0-based week numbers
      timerID = setTimeout(() => setWeekNumber((weekNumber % 52) + 1), timeToNextIncrement);
      setWeekNumber(weekNumber);
      setWeekNumberLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (disposed) return; // component was unmounted/result is stale, do nothing
      // something went wrong with getting the week number
      console.error("failed to get week number", err);
      setWeekNumber(-1); // <- use what you want here (e.g. locally calculated number?)
      setWeekNumberLoading(false);
    });

  return () => {
    timerID && clearTimeout(timerID); // clear the timer, if set
    disposed = true;                  // ignore the result of any pending promises
  }
}, [weekNumber]); // rerun when weekNumber is changed
```

**Note:** Making use of a third-party `useAsyncEffect` implementation can simplify the above code.

---

To further reduce the chances of hitting your Cloud Function, you can make use of CDN and browser caches using the [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header and its relatives. For the best results, [serve your function behind Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) so you can use its CDN too.

In the below code sample we use `public` to tell any cache to store the response, `immutable` to indicate that the response won't change until it expires (at the time of writing, this is a new directive and [has limited **client** support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_cache-control_immutable)) and an `Expires` header set to the next occurrence of `Sunday 00:00`.

```js
exports.getWeekNumberApi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const expiresDate = getDateForFutureSundayAtMidnight();

        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, immutable'); // cache in any CDN, won't change until it expires
        res.setHeader('Expires', expiresDate.toGMTString()); // when this entry expires
        res.json({
            week: getWeekNumber(new Date()),
            expires: expiresDate.getTime()
        });
    })
});
```